# 3d matrix inline initialization

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, initialization

Is there any way to inline initialize a 3D matrix in MATLAB in a single line? Thus, without use of for-loops and pre-initialization, e.g. via `zero(a,b,c)`. As far as I know we can only do 2D as in:

```
matr=[1,2;3,4]
```

where `,` and `;` indicate the two dimensions. Is there any deliminator for the third dimension that I do not know about? I know that the a multi-line initilization is possible via

```
matr(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 9 8 7; 4 6 5];
matr(:,:,2) = [0 3 2; 8 8 4; 5 3 5];
matr(:,:,3) = [6 4 7; 6 8 5; 5 4 3];
```

Comment: Here is the official doc concerning the creation/manipulation of multi-dimensional arrays http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html

Comment: This is weird bahaviour?!? `matr(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 9 8 7; 4 6 5];` initialises a `3x3 double`, and not a `3x3x1 double`; then the second line suddenly is able to add a dimension to an existing array. I always thought that'd give you a "dimension mismatch" error. Seems like you learn something every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html?searchHighlight=cat) to concatenate along the third dimension:

```
cat(3, [1 2 3; 9 8 7; 4 6 5], [0 3 2; 8 8 4; 5 3 5], [6 4 7; 6 8 5; 5 4 3])
```

You can also achieve this using `reshape`:

```
reshape([[1 2 3; 9 8 7; 4 6 5], [0 3 2; 8 8 4; 5 3 5], [6 4 7; 6 8 5; 5 4 3]], [3,3,3])
```

Comment: The second one does not give the correct results (actually, this was what I was trying first, too). Here, `permute(reshape([1 2 3; 9 8 7; 4 6 5;0 3 2; 8 8 4; 5 3 5; 6 4 7; 6 8 5; 5 4 3].',[3,3,3]),[2,1,3])` gives the correct matrix.

Comment: @Nemesis still a poor choice compared to `cat` though